# Ordering Stacked Column Chart Series SSRS 2008

Tags: column, reporting-services, chart

I am working with SQL Server Reporting 2008. I have a stacked column chart.There are around 8-10 series stacked on each other. I want my series to come in a defined order from Top to bottom. I have limitation that I can not have the dessired order from SQL query. Is there any way to order dynamic series or some kind of expression could be added to the chart?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by setting up a custom expression for my "Series Group" field's sorting expression and it worked as desired :-).